# LARAVEL - Customize response headers when using rate limiting middleware

Tags: php, laravel, rate-limiting

I am developing a project in **laravel8** (which is still new) and I want to hide some **custom response headers**(starting with x-) like:

```
X-RateLimit-Limit: 15
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 14
```

[image]

I want to customize this behavior and hide these headers, how can I easily find code (in a framework), which set's these headers

My code:

```php
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(15);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we can create a new `App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleRequests` class which will extend original `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests`. And override the method `getHeaders` to your own that will return empty array.

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests as OriginalThrottleRequests;

/**
...
 */
class ThrottleRequests extends OriginalThrottleRequests
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function getHeaders($maxAttempts, $remainingAttempts, $retryAfter = null)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

And then all you need to do is to change middleware definitions inside `app/Http/Kernel.php` file. Property `$routeMiddleware` where you register 'throttle' middleware `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class` you can change to your own implementation `\App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class`.

In my case it is:

```php
    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        //...
        'throttle' => \App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        //...
    ];
```